# Symfony 1.4 and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, symfony-1.4

As mentionned in the title I want to use `angularJS` with `Symfony1.4`.

Is that possible? and How to integrate this framework with `Symfony1.4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.
If you are familiar with AngularJS you should now that the important things to be considered is to import correctly the script files, and to declare correctly your app and controller.

The same has to be done in Symfony, importing scripts and declaring Angular app. 
I'm actually using it, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need integrate Angular with Symfony because Angular is a Javascript framework (client) and Symfony its a PHP Framework (Server). simply you can make a API with symfony a simple static entry point for start the angular application and use the API from the Angular App